# Windows Media Center Online TV Plugin

Tags: windows-media-center

There are tons of (free) online channels and websites dedicated to those channels. However, I have yet to see a plugin that combines them under one "umbrella" and allows users to view them from Windows Media Center itself.

Is there such a plugin or am I just dreaming?

Thanks!

*EDIT: I guess I was just dreaming :-)

Answer (score 1):

I use two such plugins on my Windows 7 HTPC:

[**TunerFreeMCE**](http://www.milliesoft.co.uk/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=9:iplayer-mce&catid=1:software&Itemid=11): This is great if you live in the UK, but the UK channels will be blocked to people in other countries.  There is an option to connect through VPN though, which I use to connect the Hulu in the US.

[**MiraWorldTV**](http://mirawebware.com/): This gives you access to channels from all over the world, which is pretty fascinating.  I am using the beta version for Windows 7.

The [**MSN Video Player**](http://www.microsoft.com/uk/windows/msnvideoplayer/default.aspx) is worth having too.

I also recommend installing [**Boxee**](http://www.boxee.tv/), which gives you access to a whole load of stuff, including YouTube, using an interface suitable for using from the sofa ten feet away, using a remote control.